# I need to pass numerical arguments to a onclick function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I need to pass numerical arguments to a onclick function inside anchor tag in javascript.I wrote the code as follows but its not working.

```js
var lat1=latitude;
var lon1=longtitude;

u.append('<a data-role="button" id="direction" onclick="showDirection(lat1,lon1)" >View directions</a>');
```

Comment: Is your function working?

Comment: What is the meaning of "is not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string concatenation for that:

```
u.append('<a data-role="button" id="direction" onclick="showDirection(' + lat1 + ',' + lon1 + ')" >View directions</a>');
```

That said, `onxyz` attributes aren't usually the best way to hook up event handlers. Consider:

```
var a = $('<a data-role="button" id="direction">View directions</a>');
a.appendTo(u);
a.on("click", showDirection.bind(a[0], lat1, lon1));
```

...if you want their values as of when you hook up the handler, or

```
var a = $('<a data-role="button" id="direction">View directions</a>');
a.appendTo(u);
a.on("click", function() {
    showDirection.call(this, lat1, lon1);
});
```

...if you want their values as of when the click occurs.